# Getting unexpected disconnect while trying to install Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

I am attempting to install Homebrew on my Mac but ran into this sequence of errors.

Which steps should I take to solve this problem?

```
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/rm -f /tmp/.com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand.in-progress
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 250680, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (461/461), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (327/327), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 HTTP/2 stream 5 was reset66.00 KiB/s
error: 5216 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Failed during: /usr/bin/git fetch --force origin
```

I ran this from Terminal to initiate the install:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```